# How to get top users from office 365 usage data

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Senior management at my company have requested me to provide a report of our office 365 usage for the past one year as follows :

1) Highest Overall user ( Sharepoint)

2) Highest Overall user (Yammer)

3)Highest Overall OneDrive user

4) Highest Overall Teams user

I have looked at the usage reports on office 365 admin center but it only shows report for data up to 180 days ago. My search on the internet led me to the [office 365 reporting API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/usage-analytics/usage-analytics-data-model?view=o365-worldwide). In it, it states that there is the user activity data table which "contains data about each user who had an activity in any of the services in the previous month."

My question is how can I get user activity data (as per my requirement) that is, for the past **one year**?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you said, for the Graph Reporting API, You can use the reports API to get the data that's available in all usage reports, including organization-level summaries per service, entity-level (user, sites, accounts) usage information for the last 7/30/90/180 days, and daily activity aggregates.

If you really need to get all the logs for last 1 year, it will be better to open a service request to see if there are other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks alot I will try that.

Comment: @Donspeck If possible, please share us with your progress with the support team here. It will help other community members.